# Pausable Contract in OpenZeppelin

Tags: ico, tokens, openzeppelin

I'm trying to create a crowdsale contract with [open-zeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity).

I want to pause the sale of tokens during the ICO period. I see there is this [Pausable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/lifecycle/Pausable.sol) which is to pause the contract (as per my understanding). I've called this pausable function in my crowdsale contract like the following:

```
contract SampleCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, Pausable {


  function SampleCrowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, uint256 _cap, address _wallet) public
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet)
  {

  }

  function createTokenContract() internal returns (MintableToken) {
    return new SampleCrowdsaleToken();
  }

}
```

After deploying the contract, , in the contract management page in Mist I can see the pause and unpause option. However, triggering them doesn't make any difference and the sale goes on. Am I doing something wrong here or this is not the way the pausable function works in opnezeppelin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Pausable` contract you're inheriting from just adds `pause` and `unpause`, which updates a state variable `paused`. But that's all it does by itself.

You'll need to use the modifiers `whenPaused` and `whenNotPaused` in your contract. If you put `whenNotPaused` on a function, then that function won't be callable when the contract is in the `paused` state. (For example, you might want to put that on whatever function is selling people coins during your ICO.)